# Gratis MySQL visual query builder

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, mysql

I am looking for a gratis Windows program to connect to a database and allow non-techie users to easily, visually, build queries.

[Update] I think that I didn't make it clear - these tables & suggested searches are just examples. I want something *totally* generic. It should query the database, find the tables and their columns - for ANY database - and offer a GUI to help non-techie users to build queries.

Here are three **Example** tables:

```
mysql> describe visitors;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tag_id  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name    | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| address | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe devices;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| device_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| station_name | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe taps;
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag        | text      | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| station    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_Stamp | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, we have `visitors`, who visit `stations/devices` by `tap`ping as they visit.

The non-techie user wants to ask `which visitor visited most stations, and what is their name, email, phone & address` or `how many unique visits did each station get`, and such like, all GUI driven.

Important is to generate `count()` and `join`, etc, without the user knowing SQL.

Any recommendations?

---

[Update++] I am Googling & slowly checking the results, but would prefer a recommendation from someone who has used a tool.

Typical functionality will be:

- generating `SELECT` statements with `JOIN`, without the user having any knowledge of what a JOIN is, or even of SQL.
- `GROUP`ing
- `SORT`ing
- `COUNT`ing

I like the look of [this component](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsiwqs.asp), and would like a full blown app which works similarly. So long as tables and columns are named sensibly, it should be possible to present a natural language type interface to the non-tech user and have him generate complex queries.

[image]

---

Please, post some screenshots with your answer.

Comment: *jopin*? BTW wouldn't this software also need to have *subscriptions* for these fields, because the table structure in itself is not self-explanatory? You are looking for *business objects* software, which usually especially allows intermediate definitions to put a descriptive layer on the DB. That's the only way your going to have *non-techie users to easily, visually, build queries*

Comment: `jopin` (typo) == `join` (inner, outer, left & right, w/o the  user knowing that such things exist). No `subscriptions` , mainly because I don't know what they are (can you explain?), the tables & columns should be meaningfully named. Sorry, it's bed time here, so please don't think me rude if I don't immediately reply to your reply.  Can you recommend some software?

Comment: This seems like something that can be easily done by writing PHP code.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that you are trying to help, BUT 1) I asked for something for non techies - that means that they cannot code PHP 2) I asked for something generic. Sure, I can knock up those quries quickly enough, but the point is that I want those non-techice guys top be able to generate them - for any given database, tables, columns - without even knowing what those are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please head over to http://querytreeapp.com (I work here) and take a look - it's NOT free, but we have a low priced plan and a free trial - it's designed for exactly this type of thing.

Comment: This is not an answer, since it is not gratis. Also, OP asked for screenshots. And - just my personal opinion - for a home user like me, 29$/mon is quite expensive, even more expensive than the whole hosting of my root webserver.

Comment: I will look into this; it might well be worth th emoney, if there is no gratis solution, but, yup, it could beome pricey quickly if I get lots of users, because I require one database per user

Comment: [Update] 3 years later I am accepting this as the answer, since it [has been open-spurced](https://querytreeapp.com/blog/querytree-open-source/)

Comment: Please disclose your association here as well, a_good_swan.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but the code is available on GitHub. How is it not free? Sure, the support isn't free. But what else? It's not clear from the plan why I'd have to pay for it, even as enterprise, if support is not required.

Comment: It was not free when the answer was posted 4 years ago. Things have changed since then,

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend [GroceryCrud](https://www.grocerycrud.com/), which is free.

This code:

```
function my_boss_is_in_a_hurry() {
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('customers');
    $crud->columns('customerName','phone','addressLine1','creditLimit');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

generates this:

[image]

and that's just the start of it. It is simple to use & ***very*** powerful

It is ***not*** a query builder, such as I sought, but it is well worth knowing of, and it ought to be simple enough to code a generic query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Not gratis, but affordable.  [FlySpeed Qury](https://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html)- free for non-commerical & academic use, a mere $39 for the desktop version ($49 for portable).

It has a query builder which could be used by non-techies:

[image]